# what information we get from performance_schema.accounts in mysql & how we can identify for NULL user

Tags: mysql

What information we get from performance_schema.accounts tables in mysql database.

As I can see

```
mysql> select * from performance_schema_accounts;
+-----------+--------------------------------------+---------------------+-------------------+
| USER      | HOST                                 | CURRENT_CONNECTIONS | TOTAL_CONNECTIONS |
+-----------+--------------------------------------+---------------------+-------------------+
| NULL      | NULL                                 |                  25 |              1679 |
```

What is meaning of user = NUll and HOST = Null?

How I will identify which user is loggedin and its connections?

If I checked in show processlist; I can't find much about it.

Comment: Have you read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/performance-schema.html

Comment: Please read this https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-perfschema-excerpt/8.0/en/performance-schema-accounts-table.html

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-perfschema-excerpt/8.0/en/performance-schema-connection-tables.html